# Java moving character in 2d array and exceptions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, character, move

I have this 2d array:

```java
public int[][] intmap =
        {
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 1, 2, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 2, 0, 0},
                {0, 3, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 3, 3}
        };
```

**How can I move number 1 in the array without stepping on number 2 or 3?** *If the next step is one of them, I'd like to print out a warning message. I tried to use an exception because I don't want to go outside the map.*
Here's is an exeample of a direction (from my code):

```java
public void goRight() {
    try {
        if (intmap[i][j + 1] != 2 && intmap[i][j + 1] != 3) {
            intmap[i][j] = previousNumber;
            previousNumber = intmap[i][j + 1];
            intmap[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You can not move here!");
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("You can not move outside the the map!");
    }
}
```

I tried to use `++j` at the beginning and without the `if()` it worked fine. It didn't let me outside the map but I wanted to solve the "number 2 and 3" problem. So I made an `if(){}else{}` but it didn't work really well. My friend told me I should use `j+1` instead of `++j` but the character doesn't move in this case. `previousNumber` is an *int*, where I store the number where number 1 was. In default, I give `int previousNumber = 0`.
I'm able to call the direction methods and print out the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `++j` instead of `j+1` inside the `if` statement.

```java
public void goRight() {
    try {
        if (intmap[i][j + 1] != 2 && intmap[i][j + 1] != 3) {
            intmap[i][j] = previousNumber;
            previousNumber = intmap[i][++j];
            intmap[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You can not move here!");
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("You can not move outside the the map!");
    }
}
```